# Dynamically change the size of the button based on the text?

Tags: html, css, button

[image: Button]I am new to HTML. 
I am using the button style is css as given below

```
    .button_style_enabled {
    background  : url("images/button_down.png") ;
    color       : #FFFFFF;
    height      : 21px;
    line-height : 21px;
    text-align  : center;
    width       : 112px;
    border      : 0px;

}
```

How do I adjust my button size based on the text?

Thanks.

Comment: try throwing out the height and width properties..

Comment: Setting them to `auto` might work as well.

Comment: Hmmm , no that didnt seem to work,

Comment: @Till Helge Helwig Setting what to Auto?

Comment: He means `height:auto;` and `width:auto;`

Comment: also you may need to set `whitespace: nowrap;` this will make it one line only, no breaks.

Comment: Right, that works, I am seeing that the image of the button is cut short, I mean it has rounded corners at one end and straight ones at the other, the image button_down.png is not that way, it has rounded corners at both ends. how do i solve this?

Comment: You need to have a combination of divs and two images (or an image sprite) and then target them with CSS. Or use CSS3 to round the corners, or a javascript solution. Example of techniques: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/04/24/5-different-tutorials-of-creating-dynamic-css-round-corners-link-buttons/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `padding` instead of `width` to set your input styles. This way you can still set the "thickness" of the control, without constraining it to a fixed width.

Regarding a `background-image` being cut off short, you can add a min-width to fix this:

```
input {
   color       : #FFFFFF;
   height      : 21px;
   line-height : 21px;
   text-align  : center;
   width       : auto;
   border      : 0px;
   padding-left:10px;
   padding-right:10px;
   min-width:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kBxz2/1/

Comment: CSS properties are lowercase... :)

Comment: OK , thiis does help, My only problem is the button image being cut down at one end:(. any solutions for that?

Comment: @jackJoe - Are you referring to my description? Doesn't really matter in that instance does it, my syntax is lowercase. Changed it anyway.

Comment: Yes, I was just behing picky, that's why I ended it with a smilly :)

Comment: @AdarshK - Added a solution for your `background-image` issue. Check answer

Comment: Hmmm, that didnt seem to solve the problem Curt, IS there an option to attach screenshot here?

Comment: @AdarshK - Have you adjusted `min-width` to the width of your image? What browser are you using?

Comment: Basic question, How do I check the width of my image from the .png file? And I am using IE 9

Comment: @AdarshK - If you're using Windows OS you can view the properties of the file to get the dimensions

Comment: Kurt, Yeah i had to adjust both min_width and min-height to get the full Image, now the alugnment of the text doesnt seem to at teh center, Also Am i using any property which is specific to IE, I mean if i use it in firefox, does this alignment change?

Comment: I have attached the image in my question now

Comment: Well min-width seem to have worked here:) if you see the screenshot, the text alignment is not exactly at the center, any fixes for that?

Comment: Adjust your padding. It looks like you have perhaps too much `padding-top`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
input{overflow: visible;padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was in the comments, but not the existing answers.  The answer to the stated question ("How do I adjust my button size based on the text") would be use the `auto` value for `width` and/or `height`.

```
<button style='width:auto; height:auto;'>my<br>button</button>
```